# Query not giving output correctly

Tags: sql, oracle10g

please tell me actually i want only delete entries.but i did not get in this query
I have two table the same entry is present in other table also.
and i have deleted few enteries from first table and i want to see that deleted entry using that query.but it is not giving correct output.

```
select *
from branch a, course b
where a.courseid = b.courseid(+)
and b.courseid(+) is null;
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Please show what tables you have, some example content, what you want to accomplish (what the tables should containt after your delete, or what your query shouyld return). Put some effort in ;)

Comment: I have two table course and branch.courseid is same in both table.if i deleted entry from course table that entry should be delete from branch table.so first i am finding that record using select statement which one i alredy deleted from course table. but using this query i am not getting few entries which one i want to delete.

Comment: Again: you are saying you do not get what you want. please add the following to your question, maybe simplified (omitting table-rows you do not need): 1) table definitions. 2) some sample content. 3) the restult you are looking for 4) the restult you are getting. I understand your native language is not english (mine isn't either), so you might be best off if you clarify your question with some technical data. Most visitors here would have more then enough to help you if they see the technical situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is nearly right; this would work:

```
SELECT *
FROM branch a, course b
WHERE a.courseid = b.courseid(+)
  AND b.courseid IS NULL;
```

This query is equivalent to the following query with ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM branch a
LEFT JOIN course b ON a.courseid = b.courseid
WHERE b.courseid IS NULL;
```

However it is a convoluted way to get rows from `branch` that are not in `course` (anti-join). The following query should produce the same plan and is easier to read:

```
SELECT * 
FROM branch b 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                  FROM course c 
                  WHERE c.courseid = b.courseid)
```

If `course.courseid` and `branch.courseid` are NOT NULLABLE, the following query is equivalent and is even easier to understand:

```
SELECT * 
FROM branch b 
WHERE b.courseid NOT IN (SELECT c.courseid FROM course c)
```

Comment: I want to use Outer join please give me a query using outer join

Comment: @sameer: see my updated answer. Your requirement to use outer join however seems a bit arbitrary. Are you using a tool that enforces limitations on the SQL you can write?

Comment: @sameer, he gave you three solutions to your problem. Now show some respect and spend 1 minute googling instead of also asking him to do your job.

Comment: delete from branch a left outer join course b 
on ( b.courseid = a.courseid )
where b.courseid is null 
this delete query is not working please help me

Comment: @sameer: this is not how DELETE a join works in Oracle. See this question: [Delete with Left Join in Oracle 10g](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672285/119634)