# Faster DELETE w/ JOIN query

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g, sql-delete

I have this query in Oracle 10g:

```
 DELETE FROM "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM" TABLE1
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT "CELLS_ITEM".*
     FROM "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"
     INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS_ITEM"."SET_ID"="CELLS"."SET_ID") AND ("CELLS_ITEM"."META_CELL_ID"="CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")
     INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."META_CELL_ID"="META_CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")
     WHERE ("META_CELLS"."UDA_ID" = variable)
     AND (TABLE1."SET_ID" = "CELLS_ITEM"."SET_ID")
     AND (TABLE1."META_CELL_ID" = "CELLS_ITEM"."META_CELL_ID")
)
```

which currently takes about 10 sec for 50K records to delete (and about 100K records in the table)

I know that it repeats 100K times the select query, that slows it down a lot.
Also TABLE1 has a two-fields PK, which makes the things more complicated.

Any ideas to make it faster?

EDIT:

Tried this one but it takes almost the same:

```
DELETE FROM "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM" TABLE1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT "META_CELL_ID"
    FROM "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS"
    WHERE ("META_CELLS"."UDA_ID"=55823)
    AND (TABLE1."META_CELL_ID" = "META_CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")
)
```

Comment: What do you mean here: _'Also TABLE1 has two PK'_? This is nonsense...

Comment: please give the table definitions. Use "script" tab from TOAD schema browser selecting your tables, if you were using TOAD.

Comment: @dezso CELLS_ITEM has two primary key, what's nonsense??

Comment: A table can have only one primary key.  Yours has one, while your PK is a two-column one.  That's a difference.  It is now clear from your table definition.

Comment: Could you provide as well the ddl of "META_CELLS" please?

Comment: @dezso sorry, you're right :)

Comment: ok, well, considering such model I can't figure anything else now (without giving ddl modifications). Did you try my query?

Comment: No problem.  But an idea: are there any triggers defined on `CELLS_ITEM`?

Comment: @Sebas yes but, as others, it takes about 8-10 secs

Comment: @sezso Gosh! Triggers! I'll try to disable them, probably in this scenario they are useless.

Comment: I guess you tried it after you removed the wrong join on SET_ID. But did you see my last edit?

Comment: @Sebas yes! but probably the problem is the trigger

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER schema_name.trigger_name DISABLE';

Comment: @dezso  Trigger disabled: 8-10 seconds to 1 second :)

Comment: I modified my answer with that

Comment: so finally what's the performance without the triggers?

Comment: @Sebas 1 second from original 8-10 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing your schema, it is hard to tell, but using the table you want to delete from in the subquery seems useless.  I would write instead:

```
DELETE FROM BMAN_TP1.CELLS_ITEM TABLE1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT CELLS.META_CELL_ID
    FROM BMAN_TP1.CELLS 
    INNER JOIN BMAN_TP1.META_CELLS ON (CELLS.META_CELL_ID=META_CELLS.META_CELL_ID)
    WHERE (META_CELLS.UDA_ID = variable)
        AND (TABLE1.SET_ID = CELLS_ITEM.SET_ID)
        AND (TABLE1.META_CELL_ID = CELLS_ITEM.META_CELL_ID)
)
```

**EDIT**: the above is dated now, since you modified your `DELETE` statement.  Please ignore it.

But another idea: if there are triggers defined on CELLS_ITEM, you can try disabling them.  They can chew on bigger deletes for quite long, I know it first-hand.

Comment: Yes, I already cleaned up the query, the double inner join was useless, as you tell. Look at the EDIT in my original post.  Unfortunately it takes almost the same.

Comment: @Teejay - Could you attach the query plan of your `DELETE`?

Comment: @Teejay - `EXPLAIN ANALYZE DELETE [...]` ?

Comment: @Teejay - sorry, it's a postgres-ism.  The proper Oracle syntax is `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR DELETE [...]`

Answer (score 2):

First possible answer: Just add an index to your CELLS_ITEM table on SET_ID, META_CELL_ID

Second possible answer: try the standard SQL syntax:

```
DELETE "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"
  FROM BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"  
 INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS_ITEM"."SET_ID"="CELLS"."SET_ID") AND ("CELLS_ITEM"."META_CELL_ID"="CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
 INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."META_CELL_ID"="META_CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
 WHERE ("META_CELLS"."UDA_ID" = variable)
```

--
**EDIT**

OK, if it's true that Oracle does not accept the standard SQL way (sounds odd) then you could try using an IN:

```
DELETE "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"
 WHERE (SET_ID, META_CELL_ID) IN (SELECT SET_ID, META_CELL_ID
                                    FROM BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"  
                                         INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS_ITEM"."SET_ID"="CELLS"."SET_ID") AND ("CELLS_ITEM"."META_CELL_ID"="CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
                                         INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."META_CELL_ID"="META_CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
                                   WHERE ("META_CELLS"."UDA_ID" = variable)  )
```

but I think the EXISTS query should be faster than this one... which would leave the adding an index answer as your best option. But just to be sure, try this new approach first.

Comment: Unfortunately Oracle 10g seems not to support a INNER JOIN clause in a DELETE statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672285/delete-with-left-join-in-oracle-10g

Comment: Your "EDIT" query seems to be a little faster, about 8 seconds to complete... but seriously I can't see why a so stupid query cannot be executed in 1-2 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT TABLE1.* FROM "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM" TABLE1
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT "META_SET_ID", "META_CELL_ID"
                    FROM "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS"
                    WHERE "UDA_ID"=55823
                ) j ON TABLE1."SET_ID" = j."META_SET_ID" AND TABLE1."META_CELL_ID" = j."META_CELL_ID"
            )
```

Comment: I indeed imagined a SET_ID column in your META_CELL_ID table which doesn't exist. However, I changed it to "META_SET_ID" which seems to fit our needs, but please in this case could could confirm the join? If this is still invalid then I'm sorry, just discard my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test so not sure right now as I don't have access to Oracle DB right now, but rowid
could be faster in some cases:

```
   DELETE "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"
 WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                                    FROM BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_ITEM"  
                                         INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS" ON ("CELLS_ITEM"."SET_ID"="CELLS"."SET_ID") AND ("CELLS_ITEM"."META_CELL_ID"="CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
                                         INNER JOIN "BMAN_TP1"."META_CELLS" ON ("CELLS"."META_CELL_ID"="META_CELLS"."META_CELL_ID")  
                                   WHERE ("META_CELLS"."UDA_ID" = variable)  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem was that I had a trigger on `CELLS_ITEM`. Disabling it solved the issue :)