# Delete with "Join" in Oracle sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I am not deeply acquainted with Oracle Sql Queries, therefore I face a problem on deleting some rows from a table which must fulfill a constraint which includes fields of another (joining) table. In other words I want to write a query to delete rows including JOIN.

In my case I have a table `ProductFilters` and another table `Products` joined on fields `ProductFilters.productID = Products.ID`. I want to delete the rows from `ProductFilters` having an `ID` higher or equal to 200 and the product they refer has the name 'Mark' (name is a field in Product).

I would like to be informed initially if JOIN is acceptable in a Delete Query in Oracle. If not how should I modify this Query in order to make it work, since on that form I receive an error:

```
DELETE From PRODUCTFILTERS pf 
where pf.id>=200 
And pf.rowid in 
(
     Select rowid from PRODUCTFILTERS 
     inner join PRODUCTS on PRODUCTFILTERS.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTS.ID 
     And PRODUCTS.NAME= 'Mark'
);
```

Comment: yes, you can delete using a join: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3675205/110933

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Based on the answer I linked to in my comment above, this should work:

```
delete from
(
select pf.* From PRODUCTFILTERS pf 
where pf.id>=200 
And pf.rowid in 
  (
     Select rowid from PRODUCTFILTERS 
     inner join PRODUCTS on PRODUCTFILTERS.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTS.ID 
     And PRODUCTS.NAME= 'Mark'
  )
);
```

or

```
delete from PRODUCTFILTERS where rowid in
(
select pf.rowid From PRODUCTFILTERS pf 
where pf.id>=200 
And pf.rowid in 
  (
     Select PRODUCTFILTERS.rowid from PRODUCTFILTERS 
     inner join PRODUCTS on PRODUCTFILTERS.PRODUCTID = PRODUCTS.ID 
     And PRODUCTS.NAME= 'Mark'
  )
);
```

Comment: I have tried the second one and I receive the error: "Column ambiguously defined". Besides I think that the correct syntax at the begin is delete PRODUCTFILTERS where... A "From" is superfluous in a delete Query.

Comment: rowid is ambiguous without its alias. For a delete with join, the query is fine.

Answer (score 119):

Recently I learned of the following syntax:

```
DELETE (SELECT *
        FROM productfilters pf
        INNER JOIN product pr
            ON pf.productid = pr.id
        WHERE pf.id >= 200
            AND pr.NAME = 'MARK')
```

I think it looks much cleaner then other proposed code.

Comment: Very clean indeed.  Using this going forward so others have easier time understanding what exactly is being deleted.

Comment: This one is **much** more faster than the alternatives which mostly went through a where condition rather than a join.

Comment: Just wanted to add that, if the JOIN is with a collection (table of something), an error raises because no DML can be run on a PL/SQL collection. Nice syntax, though.

Comment: does this query delete rows only from the first table 'productfilters' or from both of the tables?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko it deletes rows from both tables.

Comment: @KevinOrtman If there is a cascade delete action on FK constraint then yes, otherwise no. (look after the explain plan to see wich one, cascade won't be showed)

Comment: FYI, both tables need to have a primary key in this case, else a weird exception will be thrown.

Comment: if you do `select pf.*` it will only delete the productfilters?

Comment: This solution provides greater clarity and elegance than what I was attempting.  Using a subquery also avoids more complex unions or joins, making it more efficient for larger record sets.  I needed a quick solution to clear a subset of mixed data.  Thank you.

Comment: @chillworld Yes. I tested it. Also, this should be the accepted answer. Far superior to the current.

Comment: Should indeed be the accepted answer. Gold!

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery in the where clause. For a delete query requirig a join, this example will delete rows that are unmatched in the joined table "docx_document" and that have a create date > 120 days in the "docs_documents" table.

```
delete from docs_documents d
where d.id in (
    select a.id from docs_documents a
    left join docx_document b on b.id = a.document_id
    where b.id is null
        and floor(sysdate - a.create_date) > 120
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use the `EXISTS` construct. As described in the examples on [this web page](https://www.simboli.eu/p.php?URL_short=ORACLE_DELETE_WITH_JOIN_TABLE):

```
DELETE ProductFilters pf
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM Products p
   WHERE p."productID"=pf."productID"
   AND p.NAME= 'Mark'
)
AND pf."id">=200;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think better way are to use EXISTS

```
DELETE FROM Table1 t1
WHERE SOME_ID = 12345
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM Table2 t2
            WHERE t2.ST_ID = t1.ST_ID
            AND SOME_EVENT_ID = 404
            )
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use a subquery

```sql
delete from productfilters
where productid in (Select id from products where name='Mark') and Id>200;
```