# Deleting from multiple tables 5

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble deleting from multiple tables.
I am using the code below to delete from multiple tables:

```
DELETE
FROM usession,
  upklist,
  projshar USING usession
LEFT JOIN upklist
ON upklist.session_id = usession.session_id
LEFT JOIN Projshar
ON projshar.session_id = usession.session_id
WHERE usession.session_id       = 
  (SELECT session_id
  FROM USESSION
  WHERE delete_session_id IS NULL
  AND user_id              =
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE regexp_like(USER_NAME, 'gfcashmo', 'i')
    )
  );
```

I am using sql developer connection to an oracle database and get the following error
which references the second line - `FROM usession,`

> Error at Command Line:274 Column:13 Error report: SQL Error:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Comment: I don't think Oracle supports deleting from multiple tables in one statement.  You can read about Oracle's delete here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8005.htm#i2112830.

Comment: You can't delete from mult tables in one statement. May be you confusing with deleting from single table using selects and joins

Comment: What happens if you replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *` and execute that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete with "Join" in Oracle sql Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672082/delete-with-join-in-oracle-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

According to [ducumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems014.htm) of DELETE statement Oracle has no support for deleting from multiple tables.