# Speed up a oracle sql delete query

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, query-optimization

I was wondering what is the best alternative query for this query. (from the aspect of performance)

```
delete from CDR where anum not in (select msisdn from subs) 
                   or bnum not in (select msisdn from subs)
```

Also It would be nice if you can introduce multiple queries that can work in a same way. Please consider that anum and bnum can not be null.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Usually you drop constraints if you want a faster delete and recreate them after.

Comment: The indexes are on subs(msisdn),CDR(anum) and CDR(bnum).

Comment: why do you need an alternative? what is your current performance and desired one?

Comment: Is your current query slow?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3672285/1741542

Comment: hey, that's not fair, I didn't mark it duplicate, I voted for "too broad", lol

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one:

```
delete from 
(select cdr.*
from cdr 
   left outer join subs a on a.msisdn = cdr.anum
   left outer join subs b on b.msisdn = cdr.bnum
where a.msisdn is null or b.msisdn is null);
```

or

```
delete from cdr
where rowid <>all
(select cdr.rowid
from cdr
   join subs a on a.msisdn = cdr.anum
   join subs b on b.msisdn = cdr.bnum)
```

or

```
delete from cdr
where not exists 
(select 'x'
from cdr
   join subs a on a.msisdn = cdr.anum
   join subs b on b.msisdn = cdr.bnum)
```

The problem is you query on something which does not exist, thus it's always difficult to 
use an index.

Comment: your queries are not equivalent to OP's

Comment: Are you sure? I think the desired result is the same. Ali wants to delete all Charging Data Records where either phone number of calling side or phone number of called side is not part of all subscriber phone numbers. All columns in this query are not NULL, if they model the reality properly.

Comment: consider case when anum is in subs, while bnum is not (not talking about nulls now). original query will delete this row (due to OR condition), yours with `not exists` will not (as `select 'x' from subs where msisdn in (anum, bnum)` returns 1 row for anum)

Comment: You are right, I modified my statement. However, I don't assume it is faster that the inital one.

Comment: So what is the efficient query for this question? Is that possible to change it in two different queries? I mean one query would be the first one that you mentioned (the one that you edited) and second one for deleting rows with condition that @Wernfried mentioned.